# "'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I found the answer myself, but thought that the question might benefit others:

i got the following error whenever i called:

```
Schema.objects.all()
```

or

```
Schema.objects.filter(url=some_url)
```

or similar..

Error: "'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'"

```
class Schema(models.Model):

    label = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'metadata'


class Object(models.Model):
    label = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    # related name should not be objects, because that will cause problems
    schema = models.ForeignKey(
        Schema, related_name='objects', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s.%s" % (self.schema.label, self.label)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'metadata'
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the related_name cannot be "objects", it conflicts with the Schema.objects

so by renaming the related_name such as:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    label = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    # related name should not be objects, because that will cause problems
    schema = models.ForeignKey(
        Schema, related_name='object_list', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s.%s" % (self.schema.label, self.label)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'metadata'
```

solved the problem for me.